# signInAnonymously function isn't creating any user in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  Future<void> abs() async {
    try {
      FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      print('beforeAnon');
      await firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
      print('AfterAnon');
    } catch (e) {
      print('fail');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('anon'),
              onPressed: () {
                abs();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It doesn't create any user in the firebase and doesn't go to catch block. It prints beforeAnon but not Afternon.
Also, if I disable anonymous sign-in in Firebase console, it doesn't throw any exception while executing signInAnonymously.

In app gradle I have added `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_database: ^3.1.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the debug console ? @user270014

Comment: did you enable sign Anonymous method in firebase?

Comment: @T.TSage . nope. it just shows I/flutter (25938): beforeAnon
I/flutter (25938): Instance of 'Future<FirebaseUser>'

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya yes I did

Comment: Upload the code where you are calling this function @user270014

Comment: Remove the print(firebaseAuth.currentUser())

Comment: @T.TSage. uploaded the code. Also, I have connectivity to realtime database from flutter app and CRUD operations are working fine.

Comment: @PeterHaddad removed but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved by updating Google play store and Google play services on device.